# Does history.push supposed to render the component associated with the route?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

So I'm creating a loader component that requests data to a server, then based on the response - then the loader page redirects/reroutes them to other pages.

But for some reason `history.push` changes the route but does not render the component and remains with the `<LoaderPage>` component. Not sure what am I missing. So kindly help.

I have wrapped all pages with the `<LoaderPage>` component as my goal is when every time a user visits any route the `<LoaderPage>` component renders first then it does its job then redirects/reroutes users to other pages.

loader.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import { AnimatedLodingScreen } from './loaders/AnimatedLodingScreen'

type loaderProps = {
 children: React.ReactNode;
};

export const LoaderPage = ({ children }:loaderProps) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const session = http.get('/some-route');
    session.then((result) => {
      if(result.authenticated) {
        history.push('home'); // when user is logged
      }
      history.push('/login'); // not authenticated
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <AnimatedLodingScreen/>
  );
}
```

app.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import { LoaderPage } from 'pages/loaders/LoaderPage';
import { SomeComponent1, SomeComponent2 } from 'pages/index'

export const App: React.FC = observer(() => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <LoaderPage>
        <Route path='/home' exact component={SomeComponent1}/>
        <Route path='/login' exact component={SomeComponent2}/>
        // and so on... I have alot of routes in fact these routes are looped via .map and 
        // type-checked i just put it like this for simplicity
      </LoaderPage>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
});
```

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { App } from 'app/app';

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: try rendering `children` in loader component, as far as i know, You have to render `<AnimatedLodingScreen/>` only before the data loading is done, after that you can directly return children

Answer (score 1):

The `children` props taken by your `LoaderPage` component isn't used for render anywhere within it, and thus nothing is rendered.

```
export const LoaderPage = ({ children }:loaderProps) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const session = http.get('/some-route');
    session.then((result) => {
      if(result.authenticated) {
        history.push('home'); // when user is logged
      }
      history.push('/login'); // not authenticated
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    {children || <AnimatedLodingScreen/>}
  );
}
```

Comment: ah I see, now I got to work on the animation timing of <AnimatedLodingScreen/> as I only want to do history.push when the actual animation is done. (a split second) any ideas? :)

Comment: I your animation lasts a fixed amount of time, lets say **1.5 seconds**, you could use `setTimeout` to delay your `history.push` for 1500ms: `setTimeout(() => history.push('/whatever-you-push'), 1500);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a state to save whether the data loading is completed or not and render children based on that

```
export const LoaderPage = ({ children }:loaderProps) => {
      const history = useHistory();
      const [isLoaded, setLoaded] = React.useState(false)
      const [redirectPath, setRedirectPath] = React.useState('')
      React.useEffect(() => {
        const session = http.get('/some-route');
        session.then((result) => {
          if(result.authenticated) {

            return setRedirectPath('/home') // when user is logged
          }
          setRedirectPath('/login')   // not authenticated

        }
      }, [])

  function redirectToPath() {
  setLoaded(true);
  history.push(redirectPath)
  }


  if(isLoaded) { return <>{children}</> }
  return <AnimatedLodingScreen onAnimationEnd={redirectToPath} /> // onAnimationEnd is the function passed as prop to the component that should be invoked on animation ends

}
```

Comment: ah I see, now I got to work on the animation timing of < AnimatedLodingScreen/>  as I only want to do `history.push` when the actual animation is done. (a split second) any ideas? :)

Comment: @swoopy you can use `onAnimationEnd` event to check if animation is completed on a element trigger `history.push` in that event

Comment: yes, exactly, store the state for which route you want to redirect to and on `onAnimationEnd` redirect to that component

Comment: but how would you do it if it you were the one doing it? is using hooks the ideal approach? I just use useEffect to mimic the componentDidMount()

Comment: @swoopy updated my answer, I think it will work for you